# How to change in a Gridview on RowDataBound event the value of an Eval() field

Tags: asp.net, gridview, rowdatabound

I have a GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvDownloads">
   <Columns>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" >
         <ItemTemplate>
             <%# Eval("Enabled")%>
         </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>
<asp:GridView/>
```

The `Enabled` property is a boolean. Now I would like to display Enabled/Disabled based on True/False of the `Enabled` property. Therefore I use:

```
Sub gvDownloads_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvDownloads.RowDataBound

        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

            If e.Row.Cells(3).Text = "True" Then
                e.Row.Cells(3).Text = "Enabled"
            Else
                e.Row.Cells(3).Text = "Disabled"
            End If

        End If

End Sub
```

But it does not work since when the event is launched  `e.Row.Cells(3).Text` is an **empty string**. How can I solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: Is it an empty string because it is `NULL` in the database?

Comment: I guess it is empty because it has not been bound yet...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
If e.Row.Cells(3).Text <> Boolean.FalseString Then
       e.Row.Cells(3).Text = "Enabled"
Else
       e.Row.Cells(3).Text = "Disabled"
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

Same problem with me.

`e.Row.Cells[i].Text` was empty. I think the data is not bound at the time which is somehow weird since we are in RowDataBound event.

However, I used:

```
     DataRowView drv = (DataRowView) e.Row.DataItem;
     if (drv["RNID"].ToString() == "")
     {
        e.Row.Visible = false;
     }
```

where `"RNID"` is one of the column names in my application. This solved my problem.